# How to parse this HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Going crazy trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours. I have this html returned as a string from an AJAX request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Preview</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Connected Ventures LLC. Copyright 1999-2010." />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/article.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/css/article.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body { background: #fff; color: #000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="the_article">
        <p>s</p></body>
</html>
```

I need to get the content in between the body tags. I already tried this which was suggested in another SO question on parsing html via jQuery:

```
$(ajax_response).find('body.the_article').html();
```

Didn't work. Even after adding:

```
dataType: 'html'
```

as an ajax request parameter. Then I tried to parse it using regex:

```
ajax_response.match(/<body class="the_article">.*?<\/body>/);
```

it just alerts null. Any idea how I can get the body content?

Comment: @Zee Tee tried it, just alerts null.

Comment: Your code should work, problem must be somewhere else...have u tried logging `ajax_response`? what do you get?

Comment: Use javascript instead, `substr`

Comment: @elclanrs To paste the response in the question I did console.log so the response is correct, it contains the proper html.

Comment: @JakeRow123: What exactly do you get as response in the callback, is it a string or a DOM?

Comment: @Bergi it was a string, after putting it as $(ajax_response) it was a DOM object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REGEX is failing because the string is multi-line, and the `.` wildcard matches all characters except whitespace characters, so the newline after, say, the opening `body` tag and the body's content, breaks the pattern.

Use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` (literally, allow non-space and space characters)

```
/<body class="the_article">[\s\S]*?<\/body>/
```

[EDIT] - in response to the comment, to capture the body content exclusive of its tags, capture the contents as a sub-group:

```
var body = response.match(/<body class="the_article">([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/body>)/);
console.log(body[1]); //body content, not including tag
```

Note also we specify the closing body tag as a look-ahead, since we don't need to match that at all, merely anchor to it. (JS doesn't support look-behinds, short of simulations [like the one I wrote](http://mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Feb/Simulating-REGEX-look-behinds-JavaScript-153), so we have no choice but to capture the *opening* body tag).

Comment: just one thing, how can I get only what's in between the body tags. This returns the body tags themselves too.

Comment: Use a capture group: `/<body class="the_article">([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/`

Answer (score 0):

You could let the dom do the work for you.
Inject the code in an iframe with document.write, and then access the frame.document.body.innerHTML property.

Comment: The sentiment of this answer is correct, but you wouldn't want to use `document.write` (evil, and unworkable for any JS that executes after page load) and a document fragment is a better choice than an iframe.

Comment: Yes, he tried. But doesn't jQuery handle the iframe-thing for you?

Comment: @Utkanos: I'm not sure if a documentFragment would be happy about the doctype declaration.